# Is there a time component for each probable state of the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time

In other words, when does time or a time direction come into play or does it in the equations?

Is there time or time directions associated with each probable state of a quantum system or does time come into play only after measurement?

Comment: I think it should. At least in a (hypothetical) consistent Quantum Gravity formulation. Good insight. +1